# Function to grab specific image IDs from media library in WP

Tags: arrays, image, media, wordpress

I want to grab images 161 thru 166 without having to calling my entire media library array and having to splice those up. In time, the more I have in there the more it's going to slow my site down. Here is what I have so far, I use `array_reverse` to reverse the IDs so the most recent uploads are last and I use `array_splice` to find the images I need to extract. Is there a more direct way for me to find images with ID 161 thru 166?

```
       function get_images_from_media_library() {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' =>'image',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );
            $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
            $images = array();
            foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
                $images[]= $image->guid;
            }
            $images = array_reverse($images);
            $images = array_splice($images, 3,6);
            return $images;
        }

        $img = get_images_from_media_library();
        foreach($img as $image){
            echo "<img src='$image'/>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using custom query.....

```
$img=$wpdb->get_results("select guid from ".$wpdb->prefix."posts where post_type='attachment' and post_mime_type like 'image/%' and ID between 161 and 166"); // Query to fetch images
foreach($img as $image){
echo "<img src='$image->guid'/>";}
```